# How refresh DNS for connection in the pool of MySQL-Connector-Net?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector, amazon-aurora

We're using the [MySQL-Connector-Net](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net) driver with a C# application and AWS Aurora. Whenever the Aurora DB switches the current instance to be a read-replica (and makes a different one the writable instance), any connection in the pool that's already resolved the cluster DNS entry to the first instance will start failing on writes. Since the exception is not a connection failure but a permission one (trying to write on a DB that's now read-only), we have unusable connections in the pool.

1. What's the best way to detect this and clear that connection from the pool?
2. Is there a way to force the connection to refresh it's DNS either every X seconds, or on return to the pool?

The way this happens is the following steps:

1. Create a connection pool for connection to an Aurora DB
2. Pull a connection from the pool and start using it to do something
3. Switch the Aurora cluster's instances so that the current master write instance becomes the read-replica
4. Try to use a connection that was previously opened in the pool to write to Aurora

Comment: A fundamental problem here is that open connections in the pool have an open TCP connection to the server that's now read-only. You would have to close all in-use connections, close all idle connections (`MySqlConnection.ClearPool(connection)`), then reopen new connections (assuming cached DNS information isn't being used). AFAIK, there's no API on MySql.Data to do this.

Comment: One workaround would be to disable connection pooling (with `Pooling=false`) but this could cause performance problems from the overhead of constantly opening new connections.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger The first one is an option we're looking at. The second suggestion wouldn't be performant enough

Comment: My own library https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector does perform a DNS lookup every time a new connection is opened, but it's not coded to expect that existing connections would switch from read-write to read-only, and then perform failover. It's also hard for me to envision how that would be automatically detected; there's no notification from the server that `@@read_only` has become true. Nor is it the case that a change in DNS means that the pool has to be emptied; in many cases it's normal for one name to resolve to multiple IP addresses.